# ASP.NET refuses to respect my authority.

Tags: asp.net, ldap, impersonation

I've managed to impersonate a user successfully.  Using the LogonUser Interop, e.g.

```
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool LogonUser(
      string principal,
      string authority,
      string password,
      LogonSessionType logonType,
      LogonProvider logonProvider,
      out IntPtr token);
```

This works fine.  When I go to my immediate window and enter `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`, the impersonated user shows as my CurrentUser.  When I release this user, it goes back to my real user.  No problems here -- I'm *am* impersonating.

However, when I attempt to write a file to a share that the user has access to, I get:

`Access to the path [path name] denied.`.

I've been able to log into Windows manually as the user I am impersonating, navigated, and written a file to the share.  The user definately has administrative privlidges to the directory I'm targeting.

I am allowing the end user to upload a file, and using the `HttpPostedFileBase` object, write a file to this share.  Essentially, I am restricting the impersonation to the block of code to upload the file.  Once it's finished, it goes back to the original authenticated LDAP user e.g.

```
 imp = Impersonation.ImpersonateUser("someuser","somepassword");
 HttpPostedFileBase hpf = Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFileBase;
 ...
 hpf.SaveAs(path);
 Impersonation.StopImpersonating(imp);
```

The path is correct.

When I save the file using the `SaveAs` method, is it respecting my impersonation?

Is it attempting to write the file under another account I'm not aware of? And if so, how can I change this?

There doesn't seem to be a whole lot of control using the `SaveAs` method -- not a single overload.  Are there any other alternatives to using this object that would give me greater control over my credentials?

Comment: You've spelled authoritay wrong! ;)

Comment: Have you looked in the event log of the target machine to see if there were any access denied or login errors?

Comment: Did you investigate the double-hop as I suggested below?

Comment: @ironsam Our Infastructure team is looking into that now.  If that turns out to be it, I'll accept your answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like a double-hop authentication problem.  Have you tried getting giving the network share modify access to your site's default IIS user (e.g. ASPNET) and run the POST/SaveAs without the impersonation code at all?  If that fails, you should look to see if things are setup in IIS that can lead to server hop authentication issues.  Here might be a good place to start:

http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2008/08/22/iis-windows-authentication-and-the-double-hop-issue.aspx

Comment: Sounds like double-hop to me, when your app is trying to access the remote machine it's probably using the account assigned to your AppPool.  Look at the logs on the remote machine for failed login's to confirm the account used for remote access.

Comment: +1 - I have seen this issue before and it was due to the double-hop.

Answer (score 0):

You say "write a file to this share."  There are separate permissions for the share than there are for the folder on the computer.  Have you checked the shares permissions?

Comment: I logged in as the user, via the normal user authentication in windows, navigated to the share, and was able to write.  Same machine as I'm running the code, which is attempting to access the share, from.

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting your LogonSessionType value. I think in order to save to a network share, you need to have it as "Network", while the default is "Interactive".

Further details: [How To: Use Impersonation and Delegation in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647404.aspx)